# Getting System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception Exception while retrieving app path

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to run another command-line app in my project. To run it I need its path so, I am trying to get the path through `GetExecutionAssebly().Location`

The problem is my console is another library. So when I am trying to run that console app I am getting unhandled exception saying:

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'`

my code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string consoleApp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Utilities\app.exe";
            string param = string.Format("-v quiet \"{0}\"", consoleApp);
            ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo(consoleApp, param);
            Process mProcess = null;
            mProcess = Process.Start(pi);
            Console.WriteLine(pi);
        }
```

[image: Project Directory Structure]

Comment: I want to achieve it dynamically so if I run it on another machine it will the path automatically

Comment: So, when you checked the value of `consoleApp`  was it the right path? did you even check?

Comment: I am getting this:

"C:\\Users\\admin\\source\\repos\\Practice\\Practice\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\Utilities\\app.exe"

This is taking me to the bin folder and my application is not in bin folder

Comment: What is the correct path?

Comment: C:\Users\admin\source\repos\Practice\App\Utilities. I want to get this path

Comment: is app.exe in your project files ? if so mark it as "Copy to output"

Comment: Yes, You can check the screenshot.

Comment: you can define the exe path in some config file and read from it. so that it will be dynamic @RabnerCasandara

Comment: How ?

does it work on other machines ?